# Adding additional column in SQL query, which contains same info as previous, but more filtered

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, left-join

I have this struggle (bit noob with SQL) to add additional column in SQL query, which contains same info as other column, but more filtered. I will give an example and explain a bit:

```
SELECT 
    aMain.MaintGroupName,
    CCALARMS = (SELECT COUNT(ALARMIDKEY) --subquery begins
                FROM REPORTER.REPORTER_STATUS
                WHERE
                    (MAINTMODECRONTAB != 'Y'
                     AND SUPPRESSESCL < 4
                     AND SPMAUTO != 1
                     AND ORIGINALSEVERITY > 0)
                     AND ((AIWAVER = 3 AND EVENTACTOR = 1)
                          OR
                          ((AIWAVER < 3 OR AIWAVER IS NULL)
                           AND ((CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 1
                                 AND ORIGINALSEVERITY = 5)
                                OR (CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 2)
                                OR (ALERTGROUP = 'CHECKLIST')
                               )
                          )
                         )
               ), --subquery ends
    COUNT(rSTA.ALARMIDKEY) -- same column as previous, but with no conditions
FROM 
    REPORTER.reporter.REPORTER_STATUS rSTA
INNER JOIN
    AIWA2.dbo.MaintGroup aMain ON aMain.MaintGroupId = rSTA.ALARMOWNERID
GROUP BY 
    aMain.MaintGroupName
```

I want this to get me Group name, Alarms with special condition, same alarms without any condition and group everything by group name (showing me specific alarms and all alarms for every group). This query shows me a group name & all alarms grouped by correctly, but those "CCALARMS" are just shown counted for every group, not grouped by. What condition should I add so that this count in a subquery would be grouped by in a query? Maybe something like rSTA.ALARMIDKEY = CCALARM.ALARMIDKEY is needed in additional join?

Here's what I get now, as you can see for every group CCALARMS are counted. Wonder how I should distribute it though. [ALARM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqIh9.jpg)

Hope it was clear what I want to achieve, if not, please let me know I'll give more details. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We're using Microsoft SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT 
    aMain.MaintGroupName,
    CCALARMS = COUNT(
                 CASE WHEN                     
                    (MAINTMODECRONTAB != 'Y'
                     AND SUPPRESSESCL < 4
                     AND SPMAUTO != 1
                     AND ORIGINALSEVERITY > 0)
                     AND ((AIWAVER = 3 AND EVENTACTOR = 1)
                          OR
                          ((AIWAVER < 3 OR AIWAVER IS NULL)
                           AND ((CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 1
                                 AND ORIGINALSEVERITY = 5)
                                OR (CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 2)
                                OR (ALERTGROUP = 'CHECKLIST')
                               )
                          )
                         )
                THEN rSTA.ALARMIDKEY END), 
    COUNT(rSTA.ALARMIDKEY) -- same column as previous, but with no conditions
FROM 
    REPORTER.reporter.REPORTER_STATUS rSTA
INNER JOIN
    AIWA2.dbo.MaintGroup aMain ON aMain.MaintGroupId = rSTA.ALARMOWNERID
GROUP BY 
    aMain.MaintGroupName
```

Please check parenthesis, not tested

Comment: Hmm well even though it takes +10 minutes it seems to provide some kind of output, probably correct one. Do you have an idea how to optimize queries to run faster? I wonder if it takes some time because of the conditions or much data.

Comment: Expressions in the SELECT list (provided they don't include subqueries) like this one have very little impact on an execution plan. Does Sql server Studio advice to create/modify any index ?

Comment: You may wish to open a separate perfomance question specifying table and indexes definitions, and an execution plan.